# Html Code in my JSP page showing error

Tags: html, jsp

This is my html code given below:

```
<td> <a href="javascript:confirmGo('Sure to delete this record?','deletedb.jsp?id="+jobid+"')">Delete</a></td>
```

It is showing following exceptions:

```
  Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Invalid location of tag (td).
    - Invalid location of text (+) in tag 
     (<a>).
    - Invalid location of text (+"')") in 
     tag (<a>).
    - Undefined attribute name (jobid).
```

Please help me to correct it.

Comment: Please post complete html/jsp

Comment: Is that a JSP error or is it output from some validation routine in your IDE?

Comment: I think there is a mismatch of quotes closing or writing code like this. please find it and help me.

Comment: @a.n.m.ronychowdhury Please verify,. it works fine. answer posted

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me, tested [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script>
        var jobid = 23;

        function confirmGo(msg,url){
            alert(msg);
            alert(url);
        }
    </script>

<body>
    <td> <a href="javascript:confirmGo('Sure to delete this record?','deletedb.jsp?id='+jobid)">Delete</a></td>

</body>

</html>
```